# Find the matrix of a linear map $V \to V$, where $V \cong \Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am quite new to linear maps, and I have missed a lecture, and for these reasons I am little bit struggling with the exercises I have to do.

I have the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a $3$-dimensional space with basis $⟨v_1, v_2, v_3⟩$ and $f : V → V$ a linear map. Find the matrix of $f$ for the following three definitions of $f$.
>      \begin{align}
>       f(v1) &= v2 + v3\\
>       f(v2) &= v1 + v3\\
>       f(v3) &= v1 + v2
>     \end{align}
>   (Other definitions follow.)

I understand that for every linear map there's an associated matrix in some way, but I am not seeing well the connection, and I would not know how to solve this problem, even if it might be the easiest problem regarding this topic.

Of course, I am missing some key points, but, as I said, since I missed a lecture, I a bit in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Any basis $(E_i)$ of a finite-dimensional (say, $n$-dimensional) vector space $V$ determines a matrix representation of any linear transformation $f: V \to V$ as follows:

For each basis vector $v_j$, $f(v_j)$ is again some vector in $V$, and since $(v_j)$ is a basis of $V$, we can write 
$$f(v_j) = f_{j1} v_1 + \cdots f_{jn} v_n$$
for some unique coefficients $f_{ij}$. Then the matrix representation for $f$ (with respect to the basis $(v_i)$ is
$$[f] := \begin{pmatrix}f_{11} & \cdots & f_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_{n1} & \cdots & f_{nn}\end{pmatrix},$$
that is, the matrix with $(i, j)$ entry $f_{ij}$.

Now, for any vector $X \in V$, we can write $$X = X_1 v_1 + \cdots + X_n v_n$$ for some unique coefficients $v_i$, in which case the matrix representation of $X$ is the column vector
$$[X] := \begin{pmatrix}X_1\\ \vdots \\ X_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

Since $f$ is linear, we have
$$f(X)
= f(X_1 v_1 + \cdots + X_n v_n)
= X_1 f(v_1) + \cdots + X_n f(v_n),$$
and so $f(X)$ has matrix representation
$$[f(X)] := X_1 \begin{pmatrix}f_{11} \\ \vdots \\ f_{n1}\end{pmatrix} + \cdots + X_n \begin{pmatrix}f_{1n} \\ \vdots \\ f_{nn}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}f_{11} X_1 + \cdots + f_{1n} X_n \\ \vdots \\ f_{n1} X_1 + \cdots + f_{nn} X_n\end{pmatrix} = [f][X].$$ In short, evaluating the map $f$ on a vector $X$ corresponds simply to multiplying the column vector $[X]$ by the matrix $[f]$ on the left.

> **Example** In the example in the question above, we have that $$f(v_1) = v_2 + v_3 = (0) v_1 + (1) v_2 + (1) v_3,$$ so by definition, the first column of the matrix $[f]$ has entries $f_{11} = 0$, $f_{21} = 1$, $f_{31} = 1$. Likewise, the rules for $f(v_j), \, j = 2, 3$ gives the entries of the second and third columns.

Answer (score 1):

The associated matrix displays $f(v_i)$ down the columns in terms of the basis elements. So your matrix will be a 3 x 3. 
The first column would be $(0,1,1)^T$. Can you now find the other two columns and create the matrix?

Comment: That is correct. 
The guy above gives the explanation I was about to write :P